# Simple SQL statement in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying what should be a simple task in Access. Basically to create a new table based on a string matching query. The Hazus_Schools table already exists in my database. The Hazus_Public does not, and I'm trying to create it. The PUBLIC field is a calculated column from another field. The following snippet

```
SELECT * FROM Hazus_Schools INTO Hazus_Public
WHERE Type = "PUBLIC";
```

Gives me the following error:

```
Syntax error in FROM clause
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: Put `into` before `from`.

Comment: I tried this SELECT *  INTO Hazus_Public FROM Hazus_Schools
WHERE Type = "PUBLIC"; but got another error "calculated columns are not allowed in SELECT INTO statements" How can I make the column non-calculated?

Answer (score 2):

The order of your INTO and FROM is off, see [W3schools Select Into](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)

Try the following:

```
SELECT * 
INTO Hazus_Public
FROM Hazus_Schools
WHERE Type = "PUBLIC"
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error "Calculated Columns are not allowed in SELECT INTO statements". Please recall the "PUBLIC" field is a calculated column in Access

Comment: If you google that error: 'Calculated columns are not allowed into SELECT INTO statements, the first link refers to a SO issue that will help you resolve this. It will involve creating a blank table with the same fields as your Hazus_Schools table and appending the SELECT INTO query to the Hazus_Public table.